# How can make pandas columns compare check cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two file.
a.txt has the below data.

```
Zone,Aliase1,Aliase2
VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1,VNX7600SPB3,8B3_H1
VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1,VNX7600SPA3,8B4_H1
CX480SPA1_11B3_H1,CX480SPA1,11B3_H1
CX480SPB1_11B4_H1,CX480SPB1,11B4_H1
```

b.txt has the below data.

```
Zone,Aliase1,Aliase2
VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1,VNX7600SPB3,8B3_H1
CX480SPA1_11B3_H1,CX480SPA1,11B3_H1
```

I want made result about compare two files zone columns like below.

```
Zone,Aliase1,Aliase2,Status
VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1,VNX7600SPB3,8B3_H1,Active
VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1,VNX7600SPA3,8B4_H1,Not used
CX480SPA1_11B3_H1,CX480SPA1,11B3_H1,Active
CX480SPB1_11B4_H1,CX480SPB1,11B4_H1,Not used
```

How can I make result.
I tried using pandas. But I can't make result.
please help me.

Comment: Post your code. Include the error message, if any. If not, explain the expected and the observed behavior. Ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with outer join and parameter `indicator=True` and then `rename` column name and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) 3 possible values (`both`, `left_only` and `right_only`):

```
#if no 'on' parameter, merge all columns
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'_merge':'status'})
d = {'left_only':'Not used', 'both':'Active', 'right_only':'b_file_only'}
df['status'] = df['status'].map(d)
print (df)
                 Zone      Aliase1  Aliase2    status
0  VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1  VNX7600SPB3   8B3_H1    Active
1  VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1  VNX7600SPA3   8B4_H1  Not used
2   CX480SPA1_11B3_H1    CX480SPA1  11B3_H1    Active
3   CX480SPB1_11B4_H1    CX480SPB1  11B4_H1  Not used
```

If you want compare only by `Zone` column add parameter `on` and filter in `df2` column by subset (`[[]]`):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Zone']], how='outer', indicator=True, on='Zone')
df = df.rename(columns={'_merge':'status'})
d = {'left_only':'Not used', 'both':'Active', 'right_only':'b_file_only'}
df['status'] = df['status'].map(d)
print (df)
                 Zone      Aliase1  Aliase2    status
0  VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1  VNX7600SPB3   8B3_H1    Active
1  VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1  VNX7600SPA3   8B4_H1  Not used
2   CX480SPA1_11B3_H1    CX480SPA1  11B3_H1    Active
3   CX480SPB1_11B4_H1    CX480SPB1  11B4_H1  Not used
```