# Pandas - Performing left join across 2 Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (one that has list of all days in a month and the other than has days when a staff marked attendance) and I am trying to perform a left join such that I have a new Dataframe with all dates and with dates when employee did and did not mark attendance.

Given below is how `df1` is:

```
days
01-01-2018
02-01-2018
03-01-2018
04-01-2018
05-01-2018
06-01-2018
07-01-2018
```

Given below is how `df2` is:

```
date, emp_id
01-01-2018,101
03-01-2018,101
04-01-2018,101
06-01-2018,101
```

I am trying to create a new Dataframe as below:

```
date,marked,emp_id
01-01-2018,01-01-2018,101
02-01-2018,02-01-2018,101
03-01-2018,03-01-2018,101
04-01-2018,04-01-2018,101
05-01-2018,05-01-2018,101
06-01-2018,06-01-2018,101
```

Days when a value exists in `df2`, the new Dataframe shall have a valid date if the date exists in df1 and df2 else it should be null. I tried doing the below but I see it returns all dates

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left', left_on=['days'], right_on = ['date'])
```

Comment: it will because you have done left join, and your left table is `df1` which contains all the days and hence working as it should work!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, agree but when date value in df2 does not exist it still returns the rows and copies the date from df1 to df2. For example, as shown in the above example it is seen on Jan 2, there is no value in df2 but it is returned in the new Dataframe

Comment: is marked 0 -1 or a date?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, if it could return a Date it should be fine..

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='outer', left_on=['days'], right_on = ['date'])
new_df = new_df.fillna({'emp_id': 101.0})
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
        days       date  emp_id
0 2018-01-01 2018-01-01   101.0
1 2018-01-02        NaT   101.0
2 2018-01-03 2018-01-03   101.0
3 2018-01-04 2018-01-04   101.0
4 2018-01-05        NaT   101.0
5 2018-01-06 2018-01-06   101.0
6 2018-01-07        NaT   101.0
```

If you want a sort of indicator column, do this, instead:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='outer', left_on=['days'], right_on = ['date']).fillna({'emp_id': 101.0})
new_df['marked'] = (new_df.days == new_df.date).astype(np.uint8)
new_df = new_df.drop('date', axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
        days  emp_id  marked
0 2018-01-01   101.0       1
1 2018-01-02   101.0       0
2 2018-01-03   101.0       1
3 2018-01-04   101.0       1
4 2018-01-05   101.0       0
5 2018-01-06   101.0       1
6 2018-01-07   101.0       0
```

Comment: Mesojo, thanks for the feedback, just one concern I have is what if I have a list of emp_id how could I modify the fillna method in the above. Could you please advice.

Comment: @darkhorse - that will depend on your application, there are a few methods, you could see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: [indicator=True](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45475714/2901002) parameter is better here :)

Comment: @jezrael, tried doing pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True, on='days') and I saw only common fields returned back. The missing rows did not get returned..